# How to get one of those nifty images that shows your avatar, reputation and badges?

Tags: support, flair

Today, while browsing for a question, I encountered this wild Pokemon.
I saw it in his profile and I do not know how the user created that.

[image: pokemon]

So my question is, how can I make something like that? If you can provide the necessary steps to take, that would be appreciated.

Comment: @Bart: Nice title! Since we can't find for duplicate by it's name (flair) because we may not know it's name.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/flair-now-even-flairier/ ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a network-wide flair image, showing the total reputation across Stack Exchange sites for that user, totalling rep from all sites where Jerry has 200 points or more.

Go to your [flair page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2705620/assh-o-le/flair) and find your own there:

[image]

You'll find the link next to the 'edit' and 'preferences' links on your profile.