# How much leeway do we give possibly offensive usernames?

Tags: discussion, display-names, offensive

The username of [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2705620/assh-o-le) is "Assh O. Le".

However, in his defence he has racked up 420 reputation and 19 bronze badges, so he's not without some merit.

Should this be allowed as a "humorous" moniker?
Would we be overly prudish to disallow it?

Personally, I think this is going too far to be considered "funny".
Actually, I consider it to be a [broken window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory) - I like things clean and tidy (basically everything Facebook is not).

I have evidence that "offensive" names do exist, for example, a real case a relative has seen while processing government paperwork is "Long Phat Kok", and I once did some work for the equivalent if the DMV and found three people with the unfortunate official name of "Mike Hunt", but this is not one of those cases - I don't believe the person is 94 or that this is his real name.

Comment: What shall you do if it's his _real_ name?

Comment: As [he claims it is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200079/how-to-get-one-of-those-nifty-images-that-shows-your-avatar-reputation-and-badg#comment636446_200079) @JanDvorak. :)

Comment: I would _expect_ a 93 year old that claims to have the brains to know about Stack Overflow and using the internet properly to have correct grammar, but maybe that's just stereotypical.

Comment: I don't believe it's his real name. But my father in law works for a government agency and has seen on file man by the name of "Long Phat Kok" (no joking), so such things can happen - Ill add that to the question actually

Comment: note must be taken, however, that more than half of this guy's rep is from edits

Comment: @Bohemian and I don't think it's YOUR photo in your profile. What should we do about it? ^^

Comment: The user, in my eyes, befits his pseudonym.  It is clearly intended to troll.

Comment: But he _does_ have good answers. 200 rep worth of, to be exact

Comment: OK... upvoted, not neccessarily good. His top voted answer is kinda fishy IMO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18485244/499214

Comment: Not quite as crafty as those Asian pilots who died in a plane crash a few months ago (http://www.theatlanticwire.com/national/2013/07/no-these-racist-asian-names-arent-really-pilots-asiana-flight-214/67140/), but not bad either.

Comment: @Johnny Bones: Speaking of Asian names, there was this guy who changed his display name to a direct insult at me. While it wasn't a pun on an English-language slur, it *was* in a dialect that I happened to understand.

Comment: @ŁukaszL. If you saw my real photo I think you'd agree that a wombat is less offensive. Besides - wombats are cute!

Comment: TIL it's not a bear

Comment: @Bohemian: But then how do we know you're not actually a wombat? Because I'm definitely a unicorn.

Comment: @Bohemian Your father-in-law tells you names from government files for a laugh? Glad to here our data is secure.. as always.

Comment: in India Ash pronunciations is same as Assh is quite common nick name so I dont think its offensive ...

Comment: @NullPoiиteя but the letters together spell Asshole, which is offensive.

Comment: To be fair to @Bohemian's cause , even Google recognises it. Put the user name into a search :P https://www.google.co.uk/#q=Assh+O.+Le

Comment: I actually read this for the first five minutes as it being a syllabic spelling of "Ashley" and had no idea why it was offensive.  I guess I'm not in tune with the douchebaggery this morning. o.O

Comment: @JeffGohlke: Glad I wasn't the only one with that problem.  I was thinking the exact same thing!

Comment: You know, Korea got back at us for those ridiculous names. [Cap'n Kent Parker Wright...](http://www.democraticunderground.com/10023369401)

Comment: I, for one, find Assh O. Le completely acceptable, even though it's clearly aiming to be offensive. What's wrong with Mike Hunt, though? (Edit: ahh I see)

Comment: @Bohemian well if you spell it together, in which you shouldn't be.

Comment: @AsshO.Le Hello! So, what is the meaning of your name? I'm really interested to know!

Comment: @Bohemian Assh, pronounced as Ash was derived by my mother from Yggdrasil Tree (world tree if you know Norse Myth) in which is a kind of Ash Tree. well Yggdrasil links the worlds in Norse Myth in which for my mother, i Linked the different worlds of my Father and my Mother by having me.

Comment: @Bohemian and i also hope that my explanation above ends your nuking about my name.

Comment: @AsshO.Le OK that explains the "Assh", what about the "O. Le"?

Comment: @Bohemian should i really tell you the History of our family and the names of my parents?, "O" is the First Letter of my mothers Maiden Name, Le is my fathers Last Name. They have different nationality, and i became their link on having different worlds(Nationality as they live in different country and met in another one), that's why they called me Assh.

Comment: i and my mother adopted my fathers last name as a result of their marriage and i do not think any wrong thing in that, i guess you already know how marriage changes the name of the wife and their children.

Comment: What I find offensive is this inane digging into users' personal information, the source of his name, his family tree.... Enough already. Not everyone in the entire world has names that conform to your culture or expectations. If he claims it's his real name, have a little bit of trust here. And even if it's not - so what? He didn't call *you* a bad name. If he called himself @SomeRandomShmuck, how is that possibly offensive? This is the *Internet*. If you can't stand someone calling himself a vaguely "bad" word, I have some bad news for you about this Internet-thing....

Comment: YEAH!!! i totally agree to AVID @Bohemian i really hope this settles your problems with my name.

Answer (score 11):

The only reference AT ALL that I could find that might possibly govern this is the page detailing what kind of [behaviour is acceptable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).  On it, there is no mention of usernames, but there is mention of explicatives.  This username, under the strictest of guidelines, is pushing the boundaries because it's not overtly explicative, but could be construed as such.  I say let it go, it's not a big deal.

Comment: Please note this is a [meta-tag:discussion] question, not a [meta-tag:support] question.

Comment: @JanDvorak - So, what's your point? Discussion questions aren't supposed to have answers? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197552/but-who-watches-the-watchers

Comment: They are, but the point of support questions is to explain the current policy, but the point of discussion questions is to potentially establish a new policy. Researching the current one does not seem to be useful for that purpose.