# How to mine Unicoins faster?

Tags: discussion, fun, april-fools, unicoins

I want to earn Unicoins for free but I can't seem to find the best way mine coins faster.
There are also sometimes when I get 20-30 Unicoins at one time, and I think that there is some clue so that we can know which rocks contain lots of Unicoins..

So do you have any idea you can share?

Comment: Hey! how can you downvote my question?? i have the no downvote please power!!!!

Comment: I am vote up on you!!! the one who vote down is really

Comment: OH how can people downvote me? i thought i have the no dwonvote please power? i bought it for 80 unicoins is this a bug??? :(

Comment: Perhaps you should put in a bug report if no downvote power doesn't work? I don't have enough Bitcoins to test it myself.

Comment: Other users may have purchased the downvote override power

Comment: @PeterJ i think `unicoins` has nothing to do with `bitcoin`.. am i right???

Comment: @suhail, I just mined more Unicoins, convertered them to Bitcoins and bought a new PC! Better get back to mining more there's a few things like a new camera and other stuff I wouldn't mind either before the day is over.

Comment: @PeterJ can you tell me how to convert unicoins to bitcoins.I googled it but found it is not possible. you are fooling me :( this is not good

Comment: Is it me, or are the coins drying up?  I've mined many hundreds with the C# automated code, and now I'm not really getting anything anymore.

Comment: @Adam have you bought all items yet? I think it slows down as you reach the amount of coins needed for the last item. I need another 27 and now I'm almost mining nothing.

Comment: @Stijn - I'm getting there.  My life won't be complete without rep to the max and voting animations - getting about 10 coins per 15 minutes with the automated script :-|

Comment: @AdamRackis I'm done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i always believe in one of the popular sayings that

```
There is a pot of unicoins at the end of the rainbow.
```

Hint:

> target the rocks that are at the end of the rainbow it can consist 20-30 unicoins!!

.

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > 
> > > >
> > > > ```
> > > >                                                                              GOTCHA! You tried it? eh? Happy April Fools! Bwahaha
> > > > ```

Comment: Haters gonna hate.

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: I think your exoctic display name also attract downvotes, @Assh.

Comment: I think my name is just fine @ShadowWizard, Reference: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202420/236100 Please do not judge me by my na,e

Comment: @AsshO I don't judge and can't care less. I'm just saying that it attracts downvotes.

Comment: can one comment on that?

Comment: People should look on the bottom right side of my answer.

Comment: @suhail well is there anything i can do? if people cant understand my real name? please refer to the comments of this post mocking me.  meta.stackoverflow.com/q/202420/236100

Answer (score 38):

You can create a javascript script to automatically mine unicoin. Here is how.(Note:This answer is an update from [alias1](https://gist.github.com/alias1/9905949)):

- got to [stackoverflow webpage](http://www.stackoverflow.com).
- open javascript console.  ie press <kbd>F12</kbd>.

then define this in your Javascript console::

```
function minec(){ 
  $.getJSON('/unicoin/rock',function(data) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      $.post('/unicoin/mine?rock='+data.rock,
         {fkey:StackExchange.options.user.fkey})
      .done(function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    },10000)});
  setTimeout(minec,11000);
}
minec();
```

**[a gist example](https://gist.github.com/suhailvs/9909834)**

### Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: @TravisJ just copy the code. `F12` then paste it in the console. it works fine for me even now

Comment: After a while, I'm getting mostly 0s. Kind of regret some of my purchases now!

Comment: Works for me too - but mostly zeroes also.  I think there's some throttling code or something

Comment: So I accidentally left this running on my work computer earlier... yeah, still getting unicoins. I will be trading for bacon, or any other variation of pork.

Answer (score 21):

Click harder.  It's the only way.

Or for the low, low price of 75 unicoins I'll sell you my unicoin synthesizer.  It's slightly used, but still synthesizes unicoins at a rate of 17 per rainbow-interval.  It'll pay for itself in three unicorns or less.

Answer (score 15):

Actually, **just for fun**  there is an automatic method:

Login to SO, open a web dev console (ctrl+shift+j on chrome), paste this code and hit enter. There is a limit for mining for about ~12 seconds that's why you should wait some time after one request, otherwise you will get `409 Conflict` response.

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.get("http://stackoverflow.com/unicoin/rock?_="+new Date().getTime(),function(data){       
        $.post("http://stackoverflow.com/unicoin/mine",{"rock":data.rock,fkey:localStorage["se:fkey"].split(",")[0]})
        })
},12000);
```

This is just for fun and having a chance to try all features of Fool Day. It should be treated accordingly.

Answer (score 9):

## Get ***FREE*** Unicoins with this one weird trick!

I made a ***FREE*** UserScript that automatically mines Unicoins while you browse Stack Exchange sites! [Click here to get this UserScript for ***FREE***!](https://github.com/TheGuywithTheHat/SE-random-stuff/blob/master/Unicoins/UnicoinsHax.js) It is based heavily off of [this](https://gist.github.com/alias1/9905949) script by alais1.

<sup>Prohibited where void. TheGuywithTheHat, hereafter referred to as the Author, is not responsible for this UserScript, hereafter referred to as the Script. Any bodily harm, viruses, malware, bans, and other damages to the user of the Script (hereafter referred to as the User) the User's property, or the User's friends, enemies, or family members resulting from or not resulting from the use or lack of use of the Script shall not be blamed upon the Script, the Author, or anyone associated with or not associated with the Author or the Script.</sup>

---

### Important: Because of [the law of diminishing returns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227553/238586), you need to occasionally manually go to the Unicoin popup and click the `mine coins` button.

No this is not another April Fool's joke. It does actually work. Here is the source, for those who don't want to click that link:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name UnicoinHax
// @namespace http://stackexchange.com
// @description Constantly gives you Unicoins whenever you visit a Stack Exchange site
// @include          http://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include          https://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include          http://*.serverfault.com/*
// @include          https://*.serverfault.com/*
// @include          http://*.superuser.com/*
// @include          https://*.superuser.com/*
// @include          http://stackapps.com/*
// @include          https://stackapps.com/*
// @include          http://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @include          https://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @include          http://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @include          https://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @include          http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include          https://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include          http://serverfault.com/*
// @include          https://serverfault.com/*
// @include          http://superuser.com/*
// @include          https://superuser.com/*
// @include          http://stackapps.com/*
// @include          https://stackapps.com/*
// @include          http://stackexchange.com/*
// @include          https://stackexchange.com/*
// @include          http://askubuntu.com/*
// @include          https://askubuntu.com/*
// @include          http://stackoverflow.com/
// @include          https://stackoverflow.com/
// @include          http://serverfault.com/
// @include          https://serverfault.com/
// @include          http://superuser.com/
// @include          https://superuser.com/
// @include          http://stackapps.com/
// @include          https://stackapps.com/
// @include          http://stackexchange.com/
// @include          https://stackexchange.com/
// @include          http://askubuntu.com/
// @include          https://askubuntu.com/
// @version 1
// @grant none
// ==/UserScript==

//You can also just copy this code and paste it into the console on any page where the domain is a Stack Exchange site:

var hackMeSomeUnicoins = function(myFkey) {
  console.log("Unicoin hacking begun!");
  window.setInterval(function() {
    $.get(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/unicoin/rock", function( data ) {
      var rockId = data.rock;
      $.post(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/unicoin/mine?rock=" + rockId, {fkey: myFkey})
      .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    });
  }, 11000);
};
hackMeSomeUnicoins(StackExchange.options.user.fkey);
```

Comment: you know the `// @match` part is inefficient? You can just do `// @match *://*.stackexchange.com/*` and the rest like that

Answer (score 7):

You can try automating it using [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/):

[image: Sikuli script]

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, to ease your job, download an automatic clicker(like [this one for windows](http://www.softpedia.com/dyn-postdownload.php?p=97373&t=4&i=1)).

Secondly, as Assh said, try minining coins near the rainbow.

Comment: see this [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/179581/how-can-i-make-my-mouse-auto-click-every-5-seconds)

Comment: for Linux, you can use this command for autoclick: `xdotool click --repeat 1000 --delay 100 1`

Answer (score 3):

Remember those old [90's joysticks](https://web.archive.org/web/20150927122732/http://computers.mcbx.netne.net/8bit/apjoysticks/index.htm#sv126) with an autofire switch?

[image: Link]
<sub>(source: [netne.net](http://computers.mcbx.netne.net/8bit/apjoysticks/sv126-3.JPG))</sub>

Now you can experience the same joy of rapid-fire blasting without repetitive stress injury with...

## Unicoin Autofire Mode

Just install the code below as a GreaseMonkey / Tampermonkey user script, or paste it into the developer console.  Once you've done that, just hold down the mouse button to blast away at those damn rocks!

```javascript
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Unicoin Autofire Mode
// @namespace   http://vyznev.net
// @description Makes Unicoin mining easier on Stack Exchange
// @match       *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match       *://*.superuser.com/*
// @match       *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match       *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match       *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @version     1.0
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).one( 'mouseover', '#uc-rockcanvas', function () {
    var autofire = false, posX = 0, posY = 0, elem = $('#uc-rockcanvas');
    elem.on( 'mousemove mousedown mouseup mouseout', function (e) {
        posX = e.pageX; posY = e.pageY;
        if ( e.type == 'mousedown' ) {
            autofire = true;
            setTimeout( function () {
                if (!autofire) return;
                var e2 = $.Event('mousedown');
                e2.pageX = posX; e2.pageY = posY;
                elem.trigger(e2);
            }, 20 );
        } else if ( e.type == 'mouseup' || e.type == 'mouseout' ) {
            autofire = false;
        }
    } );
} );
```

Ps. The number `20` is the interval between clicks in milliseconds.  If you've got a fast computer, you may want to adjust it downwards for improved mining performance.

**Edit:** [Now available on UserScripts.org!](https://web.archive.org/web/20191010121124/https://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/440450)

Answer (score 1):

You can use win32.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    bool click = false;

    while (true)
    {
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE))
            return 0;

        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT))
            click = true;

        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT))
            click = false;

        if(click)
        {
            auto target = GetForegroundWindow();

            POINT point = {0,0};
            GetCursorPos(&point);
            auto x = ScreenToClient(target, &point);

            SendMessage(target, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, 
                MAKELPARAM(point.x, point.y));

            Sleep(10);

            SendMessage(target, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, 
                MAKELPARAM(point.x, point.y));
        }
    }

    return 0;
```