# Is there a limit to the number of Unicoins that can be mined?

Tags: support, unicoins

Good job making me feel like one of Skinner's pigeons!  Clicking and clicking for what appears to be diminishing returns.  Little pellets of food come out of the chute now and then, so I peck and peck like mad at the lever.

But after 174 coins mined, the rate of return seems to have dropped to approximately zero.  Is there a limit to the number of coins?  Perhaps an exponential distribution to the frequency of gaining coins by mining?

Not that it matters.  I'll click away for the next 17.5 hours, like a good little pigeon.

Comment: well done, I have a Tendonitis...

Answer (score 9):

It's not the unicoin mine that is giving you less returns, it's your computer mouse that is dying from being clicked too much.

After having a long, drawn-out chat with my computer mouse, we both decided that unicoins were not beneficial to our relationship. I recommend that you do the same.

Comment: I figured that my carpal tunnels would give out before my mouse, but I don't really know for sure.  Yet.

Comment: A -real- programmer digs up the javascript behind it and resorts to auto-mining unicorns :P

Comment: A **real** programmer doesn't know javascript!

Comment: @MatthewLundberg Ouch :(

Comment: @MatthewLundberg lol.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if restarting the mining works. Once you have a couple of stones returning 0 Unicoins, click 'Start mining' again.

This could of course be some weird observation bias on my side. Humans are notoriously bad at this (i.e. good at finding patterns, even if they don't exist).

Answer (score 0):

I've got over 200.
Don't notice any particular slow downs.

Might need to buy a new mouse after though. haha. ;)