# Mine unicoins with shovel instead of mouse

Tags: feature-request, fun, unicoins

I request a feature which users can mine unicoins with shovels.

I've already broke 5 left mouse buttons from mining unicoins. I believe a shovel will last much longer than a mouse button, hence this feature request.

Comment: Granted.  Hope your computer is insured.

Comment: @devnull LOL.. you sound like greek god. :D

Answer (score 17):

I would prefer a hammer instead. Because it's breaking and not digging.

[image]

Comment: `Knight unicorn` that I am seeing for first time.

Comment: I just must find that ponyzed version of Mihawk again, so I could replace my avatar all year long instead of resorting to one-day only substitutes. Anyway, +1

Answer (score 5):

As described in my answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227487/is-there-a-limit-to-the-number-of-unicoins-that-can-be-mined/227488#227488), I am completely in agreement with you about the abuse of mouse buttons for unicoin mining. We need to take a stand now.

With your help, I propose that we instead use shovels to mine unicoins. Similar to tapping the screen of a touch-enabled device, I propose that the Stack Exchange dev team implements a feature that allows you to stab a shovel into your monitor in return for unicoins.

This just seems like a better idea to me.

Answer (score 3):

Although shovels are great for digging up dirt and sand, they are very ineffective against rocks. I would recommend using a [pickaxe](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Diamond_Pickaxe) instead.