# Where did this pet unicorn come from?

Tags: support, unicoins

So I was just out mining one peaceful day, when suddenly, a unicorn appeared! Here's a screenshot of it in action, bouncing around all happily:

[image: screenshot]

Now it's mining all the rocks for me. So, my question is: how did I get this unicorn? What else can it do? Can I upgrade it to mine faster? Clicking on it doesn't do anything.

Also, why is it the same unicorn as the one in the sidebar thingy? Is this some sort of conspiracy? I must find out more!

Comment: I suggested them to use a [hammer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227490/mine-unicoins-with-shovel-instead-of-mouse/227496#227496), and they provided a pet to break rocks

Comment: Photoshoped, I think not. It is on internet, so it must be true.

Answer (score 1):

It clearly depends on your character class.

You see... as I said [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227680/i-have-broken-my-diamond-pickaxe-can-i-repair-it-somehow) I am currently playing an Unicorn Paladine Rainbow Elf hybrid. That means that I am both on the Paladine and Unicorn Knight quest line - I lost access to the Paladine Ultimate skill but I also gained the winged unicorn mount from the knight class. That also means that I will only have access to legendary weapons quests, that's why I had the Diamond Pikeaxe of Muffins appear.

You seem to be playing an Unicorn Tamer class. Check your questlog, you should have received your first pet when you completed the tutorial quest "In search for an horn". Also know that at level 50 you can evolve your pet to an alicorn, but you need to go to Canterlot for that. Bring a full party with at last one Stare Master with you, that Nightmare Moon boss is pretty strong.

Answer (score 1):

It's Jon Skeet in disguise downgrading everyone's reputation points. Please do not stroke him!