# Mining unicoins is too loud

Tags: feature-request, unicoins

The clicky noises from my mouse is too loud. I think my boss can hear it. SO please fix my mouse, or provide an alternative way to mine so I can get back to important unicorn work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227424/how-to-mine-unicoins-faster?rq=1]

Comment: My solution was to use [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416748/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-in-c) Now I can mine in silence, and as a bonus, no carpal tunnel.

Comment: Please click with your left hand. this should fix the issue. if you are already clicking with left hand then please contact your administrator and also boss if possible.

Comment: The clicky noises are not too loud. You (and possibly your boss) are just too old.

Comment: so you usually don't click that much while working?!

Comment: @m0sa [APM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actions_per_minute) is a common component of any decent employer's review process.

Comment: Simply shriek incoherently about <contentious subject> to mask the click noise.

Comment: What you need is [autofire mode](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227863).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you're on Windows (at least 7, not sure which others have this), go to:

```
Control Panel 
    Ease of Access
        Ease of Access Center
            Make the mouse easier to use
```

Turn on `Mouse Keys` and use the numpad `5` to click. This changes your click-y noises to type-y noises, so your boss will think you are hard at work again.

Comment: You are a very diligent worker

Comment: @Dgrin91 And you a very considerate one, as seen by your willingness to go out of your way to reduce your boss's stress level.

Comment: I deserve a raise

Comment: @Dgrin91 How about a title change instead?

Comment: Throw in a company car and we have a deal

Comment: How about a sticker of the company on your current car?

Comment: For Mac users, System Preferences > Accesibility > Mouse & Trackpad > Enable Mouse Keys

Comment: @Bart I have a current car?

Comment: Okay @Dgrin91. Sticker on your forehead while you make vroom vroom noises. Final offer.

Answer (score 10):

Have you thought about giving your boss ear plugs?

Comment: lol man you crossed the limit.. haha

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you could use `xdotool` to automate your clicking :)

```
sleep 5 && while true; do xdotool click 1; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you can automine

```
  using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            public void mine()
            {
                int COUNTER = 0;
                while (COUNTER < 20)
                {
                    COUNTER++;
                    MouseOperations.MouseEvent(MouseOperations.MouseEventFlags.LeftDown);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                    MouseOperations.MouseEvent(MouseOperations.MouseEventFlags.LeftUp);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                    MouseOperations.MouseEvent(MouseOperations.MouseEventFlags.LeftDown);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                    MouseOperations.MouseEvent(MouseOperations.MouseEventFlags.LeftUp);
                }
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                    mine();
            }




        }
        public class MouseOperations
        {
            [Flags]
            public enum MouseEventFlags
            {
                LeftDown = 0x00000002,
                LeftUp = 0x00000004,
                MiddleDown = 0x00000020,
                MiddleUp = 0x00000040,
                Move = 0x00000001,
                Absolute = 0x00008000,
                RightDown = 0x00000008,
                RightUp = 0x00000010
            }

            [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetCursorPos")]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            private static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            private static extern bool GetCursorPos(out MousePoint lpMousePoint);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            private static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

            public static void SetCursorPosition(int X, int Y)
            {
                SetCursorPos(X, Y);
            }

            public static void SetCursorPosition(MousePoint point)
            {
                SetCursorPos(point.X, point.Y);
            }

            public static MousePoint GetCursorPosition()
            {
                MousePoint currentMousePoint;
                var gotPoint = GetCursorPos(out currentMousePoint);
                if (!gotPoint) { currentMousePoint = new MousePoint(0, 0); }
                return currentMousePoint;
            }

            public static void MouseEvent(MouseEventFlags value)
            {
                MousePoint position = GetCursorPosition();

                mouse_event
                    ((int)value,
                     position.X,
                     position.Y,
                     0,
                     0)
                    ;
            }

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct MousePoint
            {
                public int X;
                public int Y;

                public MousePoint(int x, int y)
                {
                    X = x;
                    Y = y;
                }

            }

        }
    }
```