# Link to my user on my site

Tags: feature-request

Is there a way for me to create a button or a badge on my website. That links back to my user account on stack overflow?   Im a proud member of StackExchange I would like to have that on my blog.

I googled around but couldnt find anything about it.  Someone mind pointing me in the right direction?

Comment: why - its a valid question i searched google and stack for button link and user.  Was unable to find anything besides help on how to add a button to my site.  I have never heard of flair before. And its not exatly an api. (Application programing interface) so why would i ever search on that.

Comment: You can't search for a duplicate doesn't mean the duplicate question should not be closed.

Comment: feel free to close it but why the -1 ?  Being that you feel it was a bad question i have tried to delete it but am unable to do that either

Comment: It's not my downvote. I can understand that you can't search exact since you don't know [the exact word](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200079/how-to-get-one-of-those-nifty-images-that-shows-your-avatar-reputation-and-badg#comment636499_200079). +1 for that. :)

Comment: thanks :)  Someone else will probably have come across the same issue.  I find down votes depressing i try and avoid them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. It is known as Flair. Go to your profile and click on the `Flair` link. There you can find Flair of your profile.

> [image]

(please note that only sites where you have more than 200 reputation will appear, and that flair is only updated once every 24-36 hours.)

Comment: Thank you i found it